# Getting JSON Object then adding parts to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have been trying to get a script to work for my Github site and I am processing a JSON file to get an array to HTML in a ordered list.

My code I have been using is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vvoid-inc/LillyPak-Starbound/gh-pages/mods/stable.json", function(data) {
    $.each(mods, function(i) {
      var tempUrl = "";
      var tempApproved = "";

      if (data.mods[i].Repo[0] == 0) {
        tempUrl = data.mods[i].Repo[1];
      } else if (data.mods[i].Repo[0] == 1) {
        tempUrl = "http://community.playstarbound.com/resources/" + data.mods[i].Repo[1] + "/";
      } else {
        tempUrl = data.mods[i].Repo[1];
      }

      if (data.mods[i].Approved == true) {
        tempApproved = "checked";
      } else {
        tempApproved = "";
      }

      $("#modsList").append("<li><a href='" + tempUrl + "'>" + data.mods[i].Title + "</a> - by " + data.mods[i].Author + "<ul><li>\t- <input type='checkbox' " + tempApproved + "/> Approved</li></ul></li>");
    });

    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="modsList"></ol>
```

So what have I been doing wrong because nothing is working...

Comment: possibly a CORS problem. What errors are you getting in the console

Comment: I am getting no errors and no outputs what so ever...

Comment: in `$.each(mods, function(i) {` - what is `mods`? where is it defined?

Comment: In the JSON file that getJSON is loading

Comment: I tried loading the JSON file locally and the HTML file too and it gave me an error saying "not well-formed", at index 1:1.

Comment: the problem is line 193 .. the trailing `,` before the closing `]`

Comment: but still, `mods` will be undefined - you'd need to use `$.each(data.mods ...` - if the JSON was valid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91271/discussion-between-thakyz-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vvoid-inc/LillyPak-Starbound/gh-pages/mods/stable.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.mods, function(i, m) {
      var tempUrl = "";
      var tempApproved = "";

      if (m.Repo[0] == 0) {
        tempUrl = m.Repo[1];
      } else if (m.Repo[0] == 1) {
        tempUrl = "http://community.playstarbound.com/resources/" + m.Repo[1] + "/";
      } else {
        tempUrl = m.Repo[1];
      }

      if (m.Approved == true) {
        tempApproved = "checked";
      } else {
        tempApproved = "";
      }

      $("#modsList").append("<li><a href='" + tempUrl + "'>" + m.Title + "</a> - by " + m.Author + "<ul style='list-style-type:none'><li>\t - <input type='checkbox' " + tempApproved + " disabled/> Approved</li></ul></li>");
    });

    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="modsList"></ol>
```

Instead of `$.each(mods, function(i) {` it should be `$.each(data.mods, function(i, m) {`. and the `mods[i].` should be `m.`.

Also there was a formatting error in the JSON file but now it is fixed. It was causing the errors to not display.